# Show two polygons (wrap them) at low zoom, when showing more than one complete earth

Tags: silverlight, zooming, bing-maps, shapes

How can I wrap shapes around the world, so that a shape is shown more than once at low zoom?

Example:

1. I draw a polygon over USA.
2. I zoom out so that I can see two USA's.
3. I only see one polygon: ( I want to see two!

Comment: What are you using the polygons for? Display, selection, other?

Comment: You might also want to look into preventing the user from being able to zoom out that far. I have not tried to do so myself but this might get you started and there seems to be plenty of results when you google it [Setting Min/Max Zoom](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2945726/setting-a-min-max-zoom-for-bing-maps-in-silverlight)

Comment: HiTech Magic: In this context I just want to be able to Display two polygons.
StephenT: I had considered this, but it doesn't suit the purpose.

Comment: What is the purpose for which you need to display the same feature twice on a map?

Answer (score 0):

The map data effectively has 2 USAs. That implies you should actually want 2 polygons, one of which will be hidden most of the time.

*Might as well cater for the worst case and treat a single USA as the exception rather than the rule.*

Comment: how would he denote that the second polygon was meant for the second USA though?

Comment: Ah, I feel I was unclear. What I meant to say was, when he adds the polygon to the map, how does he tell bingMaps to add it to the OTHER united states. I have only messed with the maps briefly but don't you just add (long, lat)? My question is how do you say that those coordinates belong to the repeated portion of the map, and not where it would default to if you put in those coordinates.

Comment: Ah, understand now. I assumed a relative Longitude (+/-360?) value would get you to the second set, but you have a good point.

Comment: Correct, is there no way to tell Bing Maps to just wrap it (hence show it twice)?

Comment: @HiTech On a lark I tried adding a pushpin on the main bing maps. When I tried to add pins on both USAs it just moved the pin's location to the central USA. I also noticed that when I set a pin on the second USA that when the pin appears it is not exactly where it should be. I am guessing this is a result of the fact that when you take a globe and flatten it out, the coordinate system goes wonky. Imagine [this](http://asia-map.tk/wp-content/uploads/India-latitude-and-longitude-map-2.jpg) repeating at the edges. I don't think Bing Maps compensates for that occurance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

As others have already pointed out, the fact that, at far zoom levels certain features get repeated on either side of the map is an unwanted but inevitable side-effect of a projected surface that enables continuous scrolling. This has only been an issue in recent versions of the Bing Maps control - the earlier v6.x control prevented the map from panning across the 180th meridian.

I cannot think of any possible reason why you'd ever want to show two USAs, let alone target data to be positioned on each one. So the solution is to modify either the zoom level at which the map is displayed, or the size of the application window in which it is being displayed so that this situation doesn't occur.